# How can i make images not Split on a Plane

Tags: texturing

I'm Trying to make a poster in a room and when I insert the Image Texture 
It splits diagonally. I am making a Building FULL of Pictures And Posters.

[image]

Comment: Uh Im new. How do i edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to see a screen shot of your uv mapping, but if you select the plane and use 'U' - 'reset' and then 'Unwrap', do you get the same issue? If you unwrap a single plane usually it covers the entire image in the UV/Image Editor. Do you have a seam there along that dividing edge?

edit: If you can, please look in your addons under user preferences and find "Import Images as Planes" and turn that on - and then choose 'add mesh' and then choose 'images as planes' - UV mapping is already done, as well as aspect ratio matches the plane width/height automatically. I use that in all my work as a basis to start painting with.

Comment: Reset? Where is that?

Comment: If you are UV Unwrapping, you are in edit mode. Select the face(s) to be unwrapped, and press 'U' - this brings up a menu of mapping/projection options. Choose 'reset' to undo the current mapping and to get the face(s) to match the image in the UV Image Editor.